# XPath Identify all XML Elements by attribute value not known until runtime

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

I have an XML input file that looks like this:

```
<property>
<properties>
    <entry id="55882d2cacb45">
        <location_number>1</location_number>
        <building_number>1</building_number>
        <coverage source_id="55882d2cacb45">
            <name>building</name>
            <premium>2880</premium>
        </coverage>
        <coverage source_id="55882d2cacb45">
            <name>contents</name>
            <premium>1290</premium>
        </coverage>
        <coverage source_id="55882d2cacb45">
            <name>business</name>
            <premium>7780</premium>
        </coverage>
        <coverage source_id="55882d2cacb45">
            <name>inflationGuard</name>
            <premium>29</premium>
        </coverage>
        <coverage source_id="55882d2cacb45">
            <name>terrorism</name>
            <premium>353</premium>
        </coverage>
        <building>
            <entry id="55882d2cacb45">
                <building>1,000,000</building>
                <coverage_form>Class</coverage_form>
                <coverage source_id="55882d2cacb45">
                    <name>building</name>
                    <premium>2880</premium>
                </coverage>
                <group2_type>Symbol</group2_type>
            </entry>
        </building>
    </entry>
</properties>
<properties>
    <entry id="55882d2cacc68">
        <location_number>1</location_number>
        <building_number>2</building_number>
        <coverage source_id="55882d2cacc68">
            <name>building</name>
            <premium>749</premium>
        </coverage>
        <coverage source_id="55882d2cacc68">
            <name>contents</name>
            <premium>170</premium>
        </coverage>
        <coverage source_id="55882d2cacc68">
            <name>business</name>
            <premium>1095</premium>
        </coverage>
        <coverage source_id="55882d2cacc68">
            <name>inflationGuard</name>
            <premium>7</premium>
        </coverage>
        <coverage source_id="55882d2cacc68">
            <name>terrorism</name>
            <premium>63</premium>
        </coverage>
        <coverage source_id="55882d2cacc68">
            <name>theft</name>
            <premium>266</premium>
        </coverage>
        <building>
            <entry id="55882d2cacc68">
                <building>100,000</building>
                <coverage_form>Class</coverage_form>
                <coverage source_id="55882d2cacc68">
                    <name>building</name>
                    <premium>749</premium>
                </coverage>
                <group2_type>Symbol</group2_type>
            </entry>
        </building>
        <improvements>
            <entry id="55882d2cacc68">
                <improvements>5,000</improvements>
                <coverage_form>Class</coverage_form>
                <coverage source_id="55882d2cacc68">
                    <name>business</name>
                    <premium>1095</premium>
                </coverage>
                <group2_type>Symbol</group2_type>
            </entry>
        </improvements>
    </entry>
</properties>
<eb>
    <eb_total_insured_value>4155000</eb_total_insured_value>
    <coverage source_id="55882d2cacb45">
        <name>eb</name>
        <premium>2880</premium>
    </coverage>
</eb>
<value_pack>
    <coverage source_id="55882d2cacb45">
        <name>capacity_value_pack</name>
        <premium>600</premium>
    </coverage>
</value_pack>
<quote>
    <taxes_fees>
        <coverage source_id="55882d2cacb45">
            <name>mga_fee</name>
            <premium>25</premium>
        </coverage>
        <coverage source_id="55882d2cacb45">
            <name>citizens</name>
            <premium>165.65</premium>
        </coverage>
        <coverage source_id="55882d2cacb45">
            <name>empa</name>
            <premium>4</premium>
        </coverage>
        <coverage source_id="55882d2cacb45">
            <name>fire_surcharge</name>
            <premium>16.57</premium>
        </coverage>
    </taxes_fees>
</quote>
```

I need to find all the elements, regardless of name, that have a source_id attribute that matches the entry element's 'id' attribute  (see first entry element) and process them individually. The value is unknown until runtime. Using a key seems to be part of the answer, but the element name seems to be hard-coded in all the examples I can find. Appreciate any insight!

Comment: "*I need to find all the elements, regardless of name, that have a source_id attribute that matches the entry element's 'id' attribute (see first entry element) and process them individually.*"  What exactly does "*find and process*" mean? What would be the expected output in the given example?

Comment: If you know about keys, you can use `<xsl:key name="source" match="*[@source_id]" use="@source_id"/>` to define the key for all elements having a `source_id` attribute. Then from `<xsl:template match="entry">` you can use e.g. `key('source', @id)` to find all referenced elements or even in XSLT 2 `key('source', @id, .)` to find all referenced descendant elements of the entry.

Comment: Thank you, all for such a quick response. I will try these 2 solutions from Martin and kjhughes this weekend. Thanks to micheal.hor257k as well; in the future I will form my questions better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you know about keys, you can use `<xsl:key name="source" match="*[@source_id]" use="@source_id"/>` to define the key for all elements having a `source_id` attribute. Then from `<xsl:template match="entry">` you can use e.g. `key('source', @id)` to find all referenced elements or even in XSLT 2 `key('source', @id, .)` to find all referenced descendant elements of the entry

Answer (score 1):

This XPath,

```
//*[@source_id = ancestor::entry/@id]
```

will select all elements with a `source_id` attribute value equal to an ancestor `entry` element's `@id` attribute value.

Comment: The source XML has elements whose `source_id` is equal to the `id` of an `entry` that is **not** the element's ancestor. Better to use a key.

Comment: Good point, Michael. To address your first question, I need to be able to take each element with the id or source_id and map certain elements to the XML output, probably through a for-each. I'm new to XSLT, but as I learn my questions and answers will improve...

Comment: @michael.hor257k:  Oh, well, better use keys then.  Since Martin Honnen already has shown [how to do this with keys in the comments](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42306881/xpath-identify-all-xml-elements-by-attribute-value-not-known-until-runtime/42307871?noredirect=1#comment71770750_42306881), I'll just leave this answer as-is in case it's of use to anyone in the future.